# Showing a map is morphism between varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Indeed, this is an example from Hartshorne's Exercise I.7.7., especially from [this attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887223/why-should-a-transverse-intersection-give-intersection-multiplicity-one/3899726#comment8718735_3899726). Suppose $Y$ is a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$. Pick $P \in Y$, which is nonsingular at $Y$. Let $X$ is a closure of the union of lines $\overline{PQ}$ for all $Q \in Y \setminus \{P\}$.

My question is, if we set a map $f:(Y \setminus \{P\})\times \mathbb{P}^{1} \to X$ sending $(Q,[a:b])$ to $aP+bQ$, then is $f$ morphism? How one can show it using the definition that $f$ is continuous and $f$ composite regular map is regular?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Write it down in coordinates: this is a polynomial map. (If you don't know that a polynomial map is a morphism, you should fix this before doing anything else in algebraic geometry.) I'm pretty sure you're also asking about something exercise I.7.7, not I.1.7.

Comment: @KReiser You right, this is of form [...: bx_i+P_i: ...] as a linear map. Maybe I thought it in too complicated way. Thanks!